# How can I change the order of values in a stacked bar chart in Cystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports, bar-chart

I have a stacked bar chart in Crystal Reports which is used to display the number of employees in each process area that still require training.

Crystal automatically sorts fields in each bar on the bar chart alphabetically, this would normally be fine but I want to rearrange the order in which the areas appear so that they coincide with the production sequence.

I thought that I would be able to rearrange the order by going to  Chart Expert>> Data>>Order and clicking on Specified Order. But this doesn't appear to be working so I must be doing something wrong.

Does anyone have any advice?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the chart risers (= the bars) are coming from a grouping level you've specified in **Group Expert** and selected in **Chart Expert**.

Here's what to do:

1. In **Group Expert**, insert a second group. Leave the original group unmodified so you don't inadvertently affect the chart.
2. Set the new group to group by your sort key – the field that specifies the desired order of the bars.
3. Move the new group up in the group list – so it precedes the original group.
4. Suppress the new group's headers and footers.

Now Crystal will first sort your records by the sort key, and then by the field you're currently using. You should get the same risers in a different order.

**Note:** If the records for a given bar have differing values for the sort key, this won't work. If that's the case, you'll need a summary field and **Group Sort Expert** instead.

Comment: Hiya, thanks for you response. Nope I did not create a group for the process areas. I simply made the chart find a new process area by using "on change of... TABLE.PROCESSAREA". I have created a group now so that I can use it in the bar chart but when i attempt to change the bar chart to use my group the group will not show up? Am i being stupid here!?

Comment: Is the chart in the report footer? You can probably restore the chart to "on change to table.processarea", and just add a single grouping level for your sort key. Not sure what you mean by "the group will not show up."

Comment: The chart is in the report header. Sorry if what I said was confusing. I used the **Group Expert** to create an initial grouping level for the chart but when I try to use the group in the **Chart Expert** I cannot use the group.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem. My solution was as follows:

1. In the "Chart Expert" Select the field in the "On Change of" block
2. Click the TopN button
3. "For this group sort" to "All"
4. "based on" the field you want to sort by.

This will keep your bars labeled as their original category, but instead of writing in alphabetical order they will sort by the field you choose.